# C++ string pass by value

Tags: c++, pass-by-value

C++ string passing by value is puzzling me here. I'm expecting that it prints out `aa ab ba bb`
However, it prints `aa aab aba abab`. Why does this happen?

```cpp
std::string s, ab = "ab";
test(s, 0, ab);
```

```cpp
void test(std::string s, int i, std::string ab){
    if(i == ab.size()){
        cout << s << ' ';
        return;
    }
    for(auto c : ab){
         s += c;
         test(s, i + 1, ab);
    }
}
```

If I replace

```cpp
s += c;
test(s, i + 1, ab);
```

by

```cpp
test(s + c, i + 1, ab);
```

it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `+=`, you add one character to `s` in each iteration, so you're passing a longer and longer string to `test` until all the characters of `ab` have been appended.

Perhaps it becomes more obvious if you unroll the loop:

```
s += ab[0]; // s is now "a"
test(s, i+1, ab);
s += ab[1]; // s is now "ab"
test(s, i+1, ab);
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s += c;
```

append c to the local string s in every loop run, so s is modified

```
test(s + c ...)
```

append c to the local string s and pass the resulting string, s is the same in every loop run